# Identify Gold Country bush

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs, outdoor

What is this fragrant bush growing in the gold country in California foothills about 2000ft altitude?

[image: flowers]
[image: scale]

Comment: I’m sure it is not. Mock orange has a round pealed flower and the scent is distinctive. We had one where I used to live.

Comment: It does look like a garden escapee though. Certainly not a manzanita (*Arctostaphylos*).

Answer (score 1):

Deutzia scabra, (cultivar might be 'Plena')is a deciduous shrub with somewhat cascading limbs covered in fragrant white (sometimes pink) star shaped flowers.  Tolerates almost any soil, but does best when it is moist & rich.  It is native to Japan and China, but has been a classic in western gardens for many years.

It is weird if you found this in the middle of a wild area, but in my opinion it looks more like Deutzia than Philadelphus.  Western Philadelphus does not have a star shaped flower like Deutzia.  It may be an introduced, escapee plant.  It has been introduced to most of the East Coast of the US, parts of the mid-west, & Utah, so it may also be introduced but not documented in California.

[Missouri Botanical Garden Deutzia scabra](https://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?taxonid=286870&isprofile=0&)

[Royal Horticultural Society Deutzia 'Candidissima'](https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/74153/Deutzia-scabra-Candidissima-(d)/Details)

[image: Deutzia scabra 'Plena']

[image: Deutzia scabra]
[image: Deutzia scabra leaf]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is Philadelphus lewisii, Mock Orange[image: P. lewisii]